# Recursion with DOM in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I was trying to solve a question given at https://javascript.info/modifying-document#create-a-tree-from-the-object.

The question was to create a nested ul/li from the nested object given.

The following is my code:

```
let data = 
  {
      "Fish": {
    "trout": {},
    "salmon": {}
  },

"Tree": {
    "Huge": {
      "sequoia": {},
      "oak": {}
    },
    "Flowering": {
      "redbud": {},
      "magnolia": {}
    }
  }
};


function createTree(data,key=null,parent_element=document.body){

  if(Object.keys(data).length){



    if(key){

    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = key;
    li = parent_element.append(li);

    }

    ul = document.createElement('ul');


    parent_element.append(ul);



    for(let key in data){

    createTree(data[key],key,ul);

    }

    return

  }


    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = key;
    parent_element.append(li);
    return;
}

createTree(data);
```

This produces the following output

[image: current output]

while the expected output is the following

[image: expected output]

What is wrong with my code? I can't find anything wrong with my logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your logic. The problem is, you forgot to put a `var` declaration before your `ul` variable in your `createTree` function. Add `var` before it and your code works. (You should ALWAYS declare variables with `var`, `let`, or `const` or things can get weird.)

```js
let data = {
  "Fish": {
    "trout": {},
    "salmon": {}
  },
  "Tree": {
    "Huge": {
      "sequoia": {},
      "oak": {}
    },
    "Flowering": {
      "redbud": {},
      "magnolia": {}
    }
  }
};


function createTree(data, key = null, parent_element = document.body) {
  var li;
  if (Object.keys(data).length) {
    if (key) {
      li = document.createElement('li');
      li.textContent = key;
      li = parent_element.append(li);
    }

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    parent_element.append(ul);

    for(let key in data){
      createTree(data[key], key, ul);
    }
    
    return;
  }

  li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = key;
  parent_element.append(li);
  return;
}

createTree(data);
```

---

Here's a quick breakdown of the different ways to declare variables in javascript and what each one means:

```
// Creates a global variable.
myVar1 = 1;

// Creates a variable within the scope you're currently in. It's "hoisted"
// to the top of the scope you're currently in, so if you declare a var in 
// the middle of a function, it gets pulled to the very top when your code
// is executed.
var myVar2 = 2;

// Declares a variable that is not hoisted.
let myVar3 = 3;

// Declares a constant that cannot be reassigned.
const myVar4 = 4;
```

The reason your implementation failed is because `ul` became a global variable which caused your function to not return a desirable result.

Comment: I just spend last 7 hours trying to figure out what went wrong. Thank you so much. Do you know what happened when variables were not declared with let.

Comment: @jibinmathew Added an explanation to my answer. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
    "Fish": {
        "trout": {},
        "salmon": {}
    },

    "Tree": {
        "Huge": {
            "sequoia": {},
            "oak": {}
        },
        "Flowering": {
            "redbud": {},
            "magnolia": {}
        }
    }
};


function createTree(data, key = null, parent_element = document.body) {
    if (Object.keys(data).length) {
        let ul = document.createElement('ul');
        if (key) {
            li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent = key;
            li = parent_element.append(li);
        }
        ul = document.createElement('ul');
        parent_element.append(ul);
        for (let key in data) {
            createTree(data[key], key, ul);
        }
        return
    }
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = key;
    parent_element.append(li);
    return;
}

createTree(data);
```

You need to create  `let ul = document.createElement('ul');` then need to append `<li>` was creating issue...

Comment: Your answer is correct, I didn't down vote your answer. I have upvoted your answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @jibinmathew I have given solution faster & with quality than Jake miller so you need to give me upvote.. right????